# The Streamlit app stops with "Please wait... " and then stops

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, streamlit

### Problem

The app started by running `streamlit run main.py` will display `http://IP_ADDRESS:8501` is displayed correctly, but `http://DOMAIN_NAME` stops with "Please wait... " and stops.

[image]

### Environment

- Domain name already resolved with Route53
- Deploy Streamlit App on EC2 (Amazon Linux) and run `Streamlit run main.py` on Tmux
- Use Nginx to convert access to port80 to port8501

#### Changed Nginx settings

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen       80; #default
        listen       [::]:80; #default
        server_name MY_DOMAIN_NAME;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:8501;
        }
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html; #default
```

### What I tried

I tried the following, but it did not solve the problem.

https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/deploy/remote-start#symptom-2-the-app-says-please-wait-forever

- `streamlit run my_app.py --server.enableCORS=false`
- `streamlit run my_app.py --server.enableWebsocketCompression=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name MY_DOMAIN_NAME;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
```

and then, use this command line:

```sh
streamlit run my_app.py --server.port 8501 --server.baseUrlPath / --server.enableCORS false --server.enableXsrfProtection false
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. I'd like to forward a sub-path 'location /subapp' to the streamlit app. If I just add the sub-path to the above configuration, streamlit does not work. The title bar changes to streamlit, but I just see a blank white screen. Sometimes the app tries to load, but the data does not load. It get stuck with the please wait message. Have you tried this?

Comment: Sadly, I have also encountered this bug. But it happens so rarely I don't know if it is related to my answer. I have not yet fixed it, but try: https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/deploy/remote-start#symptom-2-the-app-says-please-wait-forever

Comment: @vvvvv Sorry for my ignorance, but could you please suggest were to add the code you suggested on AWS ec2?

Comment: I work on a simple citrix-based connection, running streamlit from a remote machine on cmd line, please help me on where should I add these settings.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using Ambassador as their ingress to kubernetes you'll need to allow websockets.  This is explained at https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/howtos/websockets/

But, you essentially need to add the following to your Mapping

```
allow_upgrade:
- websocket
```

Comment: Can you show your yaml for streamlit service over Ambassador ingress ? I already allow websockets and disable cors, WebsocketCompression and XsrfProtection as streamlit recommended but this problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

```
--server.headless=true
```

I think the only problem is Streamlit trying to open a browser, so simply add this parameter in your run command:

- `streamlit run my_app.py --server.headless=true`

or try to change this in the config file which is you need to create:

Refer to [this](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration) explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade Streamlit code to version `1.11.1`.

Refer to this link: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/security-notice-immediately-upgrade-your-streamlit-code-to-version-1-11-1/28399:

> On July 27th, 2022, we learned of a potential vulnerability in the
> Streamlit open source library that impacts apps that use custom
> components. The vulnerability does not impact apps hosted on Streamlit
> Cloud.
>
> We released a patch on the same night, July 27th, 2022 at 2:20PM PST,
> and ask that you immediately upgrade your Streamlit code to version
> 1.11.1 or higher. You can read more in this [vulnerability advisory](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/e/2PACX-1vRzF9K6gwv9KnQz---1pt0SdHMVt-CHuKMmdTH1uct7xPcK7vToP4FvYdI84aO6rGfCmrBSaViri0Nd/pub)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the fix was downgrading `streamlit` from `v1.14.0` to `v1.11.0`.

What didn't work:

1. `--server.headless=true`
2. `--server.enableCORS=false`
3. `--server.enableWebsocketCompression=false`

How was the app deployed? **GCS** using **Cloud Run**

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install iptables
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8501
```

Install iptables using yum in the EC2 machine. Afterwards, if you have set your nginx configuration file up correct then restart your service.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This is exactly what worked for me to resolve the "Please wait..." issue after getting stuck there on multiple difference Apache2 configurations. I got this via https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1555

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me on `streamlit>=1.27.0`

In addition to the configuration that [vvvv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5446749/vvvvv) mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70184078/13400981), we also need to add following conf to nginx:

```
    server {
            server_name your.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501;
    }

    location ^~ /static {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/static/;
    }

    location ^~ /_stcore/health {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/_stcore/health;
    }

    location ^~ /vendor {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/vendor;
    }

    location /_stcore/stream {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/_stcore/stream;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
  }
```

After this reload the nginx service & it should be work.

Please note the `/_stcore/health` was `/healthz` & `/_stcore/stream` was `/stream` in the older version of streamlit

What didn't work for me:

1. `--server.headless=true`
2. `--server.enableCORS=false`
3. `--server.enableWebsocketCompression=false`
4. Downgrading streamlit

References:

1. https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/6305
2. https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-use-streamlit-with-nginx/378/6