# Streamlit Cloudfront Deployment Multipage Direct Links Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, streamlit

I'm running a streamlit app connected to cloudfront with an edge lambda that redirects to an SSO authentication and then back to the app. The homepage of the app works fine and I can access various pages using Streamlit's multipage functionality.

However, if I try to navigate directly to a page as opposed to via the page navigation bar I get an error with the websocket: `WebsocketConnection WebSocket onerror`. The network details show the error `NS_ERROR_WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

One thing I notice is that the `_stcore/stream` URL is different when deployed locally versus in my deployment when navigating to a page directly. When I deploy locally and navigate directly to a page the URL is: `{domainName}/_stcore/stream` but when I navigate directly on my cloudfront deployment I see: `{domainName}/{pageName}/_stcore/stream`.

I've tried making changes to the edge lambda to directly change the URI to match the local deployment and to redirect the page to match the local deployment. Directly changing the request URI stops the websocket failure, but I get navigated to the homepage with the pagename appended to the URI. This persists if I then try to navigate from there to individual pages like: `{domainName}/{page1ThatWasRedirected}/{page2ThatWasSidebarNavigated}`

I've tried setting similar headers as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177733/the-streamlit-app-stops-with-please-wait-and-then-stops/77521644#77521644) but I'm not really familiar enough with networking to know how to translate those nginx configs to cloudfront so I may have done it incorrectly.